# Generic minima filter

Tags: python, loops, scipy

I am trying to run a generic filter over an input array, so I can obtain a Local Minima within a given window size.

The code is this:

```
import scipy.ndimage.filters as scifil

def minimum(window):
    print window.shape
    for i in range(window.shape[0]):
        for j in range(window.shape[1]):
            window[i, j] -= min(window)
    return window

file = np.genfromtxt('E:\...\Test_local_chm.txt', dtype=None, delimiter='\t')
local_min = scifil.generic_filter(file3, minimum, size = 3)
np.savetxt('E:\...\output_local_chm.txt',local_min, delimiter='\t')
```

But I get the error:

> for j in range(window.shape[1]):
>   IndexError: tuple index out of range

Why is this? In runned over the range of the columns and rows, and I don't know why it's not working. Thanks!

Comment: What does `print window.shape` print?

Comment: That's interesting. A `shape` tuple with only one element suggests that `window` is one-dimensional, so you can't index it with two coordinates.

Comment: It looks like your file is only giving you a one-dimensional array, whereas you're apparently expecting a 2D one. Are you sure the file has multiple columns, that you're using the right delimiter etc.?

Comment: I am using the tab delimiter. I tried creating another txt file, but I get the same error.

Comment: I runned 'file.shape' outside the function, and it returns the correct shape.

Comment: Sorry for double (triple) post. I read through the SciPy documentation, and it says: 'The input values within the filter footprint at that element are passed to the function as a 1D array of double values.'. I'm guessing that I try to iterate over a 2D array, but the actual shape is 1D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because the

> scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter

transforms the input 2D array into a 1D one, and I was iterating for two indexes. I only needed to remove the second iteration, thus the code below fixed it.

```
 for i in range(window.shape[0]):
        window[i] -= min(window)
```